# why does this fork() out put produce 8 instead of 5?

Tags: c, linux, fork

So I have to find the output of this code which is using the `fork()` method. I thought the output was 5 "hello" s but instead I got 8. Why is that? This is the code:

```
#include "csapp.h"

void doit()
{
    Fork();
    Fork();
    printf("hello\n");
    return;
}

int main()
{
    doit();
    printf("hello\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't know of any function called `Fork()`. Are you sure it isn't `fork()` ?

Comment: Hint: 2*2^2=8  .....

Comment: Why would you expect 5? You fork 1 process into 2, then 2 into four, then each prints "hello" twice.

Comment: `printf("hello from %d\n", getpid() );` may help you understand where all the hello's are coming from.

Comment: @Havenard I suspect `Fork()` is a wrapper defined in `csapp.h`.

Comment: `fork` is not a _method_, but a _function_!

Comment: This question should be not have been closed. It's sufficiently clear that 3 of us were able to provide answers that the OP apparently felt were helpful. I get that some might be confused by the capital F in `Fork()`, but we can nevertheless infer the behavior of `Fork()` from the text. Please join with me in voting to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what your code is doing:

```
main->doit()->Fork()->Fork()->printf()->return->printf()->exit()
                |       |
                |       ----->printf()->return->printf()->exit()
                |
                ----->Fork()->printf()->return->printf()->exit()
                        |
                        ----->printf()->return->printf()->exit()
```

As you can see, you have a total of 8 calls to `printf()`.

It would have been easier for you to see what was going on if you chose to print different strings in your `main` and `doit` functions.

Setting breakpoint on each `printf()` call is another effective strategy for figuring out these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 5):

First you call fork and your one process forks into two. Then you call fork in each resulting process and you have a total of 4. Then the 4 processes print hello, return, and print hello again, for a total of 8 hellos.

Answer (score 1):

You create process #1. Before printing anything, process #1 calls `fork()` and generates a clone that we will call process #2. Both processes #1 and #2 call `fork()` again, cloning into processes #3 and #4. Now you have 4 processes and each one of them will print `hello` twice. How many `hello` are printed?