# Number of print statements Fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am having a hard time understanding this code. I am asked how many times it prints "hello". The answer is 8, and when I run it I get 8, however I feel like it should print 5.

Can anyone explain how this is printing 8 times?

```
int main() {
    doit();
    printf("hello\n");
    exit(0);
}

void doit() {
  fork();
  fork();
  printf("hello\n");
  return;
}
```

Comment: 2 forks = 4 processes. Each printing hello 2 times (because there are two printf after the two forks) = 8 hello.

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727168/why-does-this-fork-out-put-produce-8-instead-of-5) site.
Answer For your question is there.

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727168/why-does-this-fork-out-put-produce-8-instead-of-5) link..Answer for your question is there.